# How do I log UFC Person Trainer on Fitocracy

Tags: fitocracy, ufc-personal-trainer

Cross games, but here it goes:

I've been doing Fitocracy lately, so I've been logging all my workouts.  A friend got my UFC Personal Trainer for Hanukkah and I wanted to give it a try.  I love Xbox, I love working out, and I **love** achievements.  It seemed like a match made in heaven, except...

I finished my first work out and I went to log the activities, standard things like Push-Ups, Squats, etc, and the game was even nice enough to keep track of how many I did while I was doing them.  However, after the workout was over and I wanted to log the number, I couldn't find that information anywhere.  The after workout only had "Points," which corresponded more with how many reps I did in a row rather than how many total.  I tried looking up information in my workout journal, but the only thing recorded there was Calories.  Which leaves me with only one question:

After a workout, how do I know how many reps I have done?